# Tap-to-click sensitivity adjustment on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: gnome, touchpad, libinput, 23.04, tap-to-click

I'm having about half of my single toGNOMEuchpad taps ("tap-to-click") ignored on Ubuntu 23.04 GNOME. It was working fine on 22.10 on same laptop right before upgrade.  I imagine there is a sensitivity adjustment that can be made, although it is not in settings. I've searched around, but cannot find a solution. How can I adjust the tap sensitivity?

Second question: libinput reports tap-to-click is disabled, yet it is enabled in GNOME. settings, so does GNOME interpret tap-to-click in software or some other way?

libinput reports:

```
Device:           Synaptics TM3625-001
Kernel:           /dev/input/event8
Group:            6
Seat:             seat0, default
Size:             97x65mm
Capabilities:     pointer gesture
Tap-to-click:     disabled
Tap-and-drag:     enabled
Tap drag lock:    disabled
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: disabled
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   *two-finger edge 
Click methods:    *button-areas clickfinger 
Disable-w-typing: enabled
Disable-w-trackpointing: enabled
Accel profiles:   flat *adaptive
Rotation:         n/a
```

Ubuntu Settings:

[image: Ubuntu settings]

Comment: I found only cursor speed can be adjusted.

Comment: I never had luck with it but wou.ld https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Touchegg allow a single touch as a gesture?